# open source static or dynamic malware unpacker

Tags: malware, unpacking

I am looking for static and dynamic unpacker tools. I only found PE-Explorer the only can handle UPX packer. 
So I am carious to know is there any open source static or dynamic unpacker?

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few dynamic ones which can handle simple wrapping packers. One example is [PackerAttacker](https://github.com/BromiumLabs/PackerAttacker).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is kind of simple, I am looking for more strong tool like Justin or renovo or omniUnpack

Comment: @user2942756 I'm the lead dev on The PackerAttacker, and I've got to tell you that it's much better than omniUnpack. I haven't tried the others, but we have a huge success rate with The PackerAttacker in daily use.

Comment: @NickCano wow.really? I need to try that.. Thanks

Comment: Note that you still need a Microsoft Detours license if you want to use this tool in a professional setting.

Comment: Thanks everyone. My last question is that can I use this tool on Linux too?

Comment: No, but a similar tool based on pin wouldn't be hard to implement.

Comment: Thanks every one. I tried to work on packerattakcer but it seems it is only generate dump file while I am looking to an unpacker to give me unpacked exe file. @NickCano I am wondering if packerattacker could generate unpacked exe too.

Comment: @user2942756
It dumps anything that is mapped into the heap or into a PE header section and then executed, as well as anything mapped into a remote process. Sometimes this is a PE-compatible exe, sometimes it is shellcode, and sometimes it is data. If you're on Linux, you can run `file *` on the dump files to see what types of files they are. You can check out [our DerbyCon talk on the tool](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/derbycon5/the-3-way14-attacking-packing-captain-hook-beats-down-on-peter-packer-vadim-kotov-nick-cano) to see how we use it for analysis.